# Task 'run' not found in root project

Tags: gradle

My "build.gradle" file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets {
   main {
      java {
         srcDir 'src'
      }
   }

   test {
      java {
         srcDir 'test'
      }
   }
}
```

My "Main.java" file in "./src/" directory:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Gradle");
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Task 'run' not found in root project 'gradleNew'

Sorry for the stupid question... I didn't use Gradle before

Answer (score 2):

The `java` plugin does not include the `run` task, which I suppose your gradle build requires somewhere in your app.
Change the `java` plugin to `application` and you should be fine.
To verify this, you can go to your project folder inside you terminal and run `gradle tasks`. You should see the `run` task listed among other tasks.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just add this code and my app run:

```
plugins {
    id 'application' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
group 'com.example'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'application' // implicitly includes the java plugin

sourceCompatibility = 1.11 // java version 11

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  // your dependencies
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
    resources {
      srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
    }
  }
}
```

I typically use something similar to this for my projects. You can then explicitly create the relevant dirs for src/test code, or sometimes the IDE will do it for you when you point it to the relevant `build.gradle` file (you can typically restart the IDE and it will pick up the file, or you can open a new project and select the `build.gradle` file as the project to open if it doesn't identify it right away).